# Command to put text at specific position no matter length

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, text

I have the following code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%landmark
\draw [lightgray] (0, 0) -- (0,-1.5);

\node at (0.45,-0.2) {Hello};
\node at (1.4,-1) {Hello my friend};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It gives the following output :

[image]

I want the text to start at the gray landmark, but as you can see, when the text length's changes, the x position need to be changed as well. Is there a way to 'automate' this x edit process ? Because it becomes annoying with a huge document.
(Maybe the answer is somewhere on the net and I just didn't know how o google my question properly)

Comment: Try `\node[anchor=west, inner xsep=0pt]`, which changes the default setting `anchor=center, inner xsep=.3333em`.

Comment: It works perfectly, could you put your comment as an answer ? @muzimuzhiZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\node[anchor=west, inner xsep=0pt]`.

Step-by-step examples:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  %landmark
  \draw [lightgray] (0, .5) -- (0,-4);

  % original, equivalent to "anchor=center, inner xsep=.3333em"
  \node at (0.45, 0) {Hello};
  \node at (1.4, -.5) {Hello my friend};
  
  % with "anchor=west" added and the x-pos of node being "0"
  \node[anchor=west] at (0, -1.5) {Hello};
  \node[anchor=west] at (0, -2) {Hello my friend};
  
  % with "inner xsep=0pt" added and syntax "\path node {...} node {...};" applied
  \path[anchor=west, inner xsep=0pt]
    node at (0, -3) {Hello}
    node at (0, -3.5) {Hello my friend};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]